# Unable to get SQS message in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am learning AWS in ruby, I have the following code in my controller

```
sqs = WebService.sqs_client
    recieved_message = sqs.receive_message({
                                                        queue_url: ENV["SQS_URL"], # required
                                                        attribute_names: ["Policy"], # accepts Policy, VisibilityTimeout, MaximumMessageSize, MessageRetentionPeriod, ApproximateNumberOfMessages, ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible, CreatedTimestamp, LastModifiedTimestamp, QueueArn, ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed, DelaySeconds, ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds, RedrivePolicy
                                                        message_attribute_names: ["MessageAttributeName"],
                                                        max_number_of_messages: 1,
                                                        visibility_timeout: 1,
                                                        wait_time_seconds: 1,
                                                    })
    if recieved_message.size > 0
      puts recieved_message[0]
    end
    puts recieved_message.size
```

However the output is as follows

```
Started GET "/employee" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-28 12:43:48 -0500
Processing by PageController#employee as HTML
1
  Rendered page/employee.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2020ms (Views: 400.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have tried adding .body to the end and various other things all to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably find it easier to get to grips with this in the rails console rather than in a controller

Comment: It looks like it is getting the message and printing the list size as `1`.

Comment: @MarkB Shouldn't this line "puts recieved_message[0]" put something in the console?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I will try the console now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by studying the example [here](https://github.com/joshuago/sqs_sample_ruby/blob/master/sqs_demo.rb)

I needed to put the following code

```
  puts recieved_message["messages"][0]["body"]
```